# How to groupby a dataframe and convert it to json

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe as below

```
ID  Name    Components
1   Sachin  ABC-A
1   Sachin  ABC-B
2   Kohli   DEF-D
2   Kohli   DEF-E
```

I want to convert it to json as below
Json file should be grouped by ID and Name

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Sachin",
    "Components: [
                   "ABC-A",
                   "ABC-B"
                 ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Kohli",
    "Components: [
                   "DEF-D",
                   "DEF-E"
                 ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `to_json`:

```
>>> df.groupby(["ID","Name"], as_index=False).agg(list).to_json(orient="records")

'[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Sachin",
    "Components": [
      "ABC-A",
      "ABC-B"
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Kohli",
    "Components": [
      "DEF-D",
      "DEF-E"
    ]
  }
]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It gives correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)
I suggest you to debug every operation for better understanding, how does it work.

```
import pandas as pd


# your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'Name': ['Sachin', 'Sachin', 'Kohli', 'Kohli'],
    'Components': ['ABC-A', 'ABC-B', 'DEF-D', 'DEF-E']
})
grouped = df.groupby(['ID', 'Name'])['Components'].apply(list).reset_index()
json_data = grouped.to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Debugging did help me in understanding each step in detail.